# What's the difference between select[name^=] and select[name*=] ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to select

```
<select name="123-table"></select>
```

from the DOM with jQuery like

```
$('[name^=-table]').val();
```

but nothing returned

Comment: One does x, and the other does y. One is starts with, the other is contains.

Comment: you have never stumpled across **http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/** ??

Comment: Read the documentation, it explains very clearly what each one does.

Comment: ^ selects what starts with it, * what contains it.

Comment: -1 for failing to reference documentation and subsequently asking a question where the title and body are only topically related.

Comment: @coreyward I think you mean _tangentially related_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want this

```
$('[name$=-table]').val();
```

That selects for **ending with** `-table`

---

`^=` selects for *beginning with*

`$=` selects for *ending with*

`*=` selects for *contains anywhere*

Check out [the jQuery docs on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information.

Comment: `$('[name^=-table]').val();` is a [Starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). What you need is as @Adam Rackis says, is either the ends with or the [contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/).

Comment: and what about ``^`` and ``*``??

Comment: You have the first two backwards

Answer (score 5):

As per [**docs**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/),

`^=` means "starts with" selector

`*=` means "contains" selector.

So it's pretty obvious you didn't get the value.

You can use "ends with" selector `$=` here:

```
$('[name$=-table]').val();
```

Comment: can I know the reason for downvote? It doesn't seem to be justified.